# Tax Calculator Code Help Visual Basics

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, calculator

So I am working on a tax calculator as an assignment on my visual basics class, I have had 2 ideas for this to work and i cant figure either of them out.

A. I declared TaxRate as a double and the user would open form2 to set the rate, but how can I use a double from FORM1 on FORM2 and save it?

B. I could have the double equal to form2.textbox1.text but then I how I limit the textbox to 1 Dot and Numbers, DOts, and Backspace only?

My current code is:

```
Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789"
    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

and I cant use backspace or dots (I found this sample online.)

Comment: Why not just use a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control in Form1?  Set the **DecimalPlaces** property to 2, and set appropriate values in the **Minimum** and **Maximum** properties...

Comment: "Visual BasicS"? plural?

Comment: So I did what you recommended and added this code to a label

lblFinalTaxRate.Text = "Tax Rate: " NumUpDownTaxRate.Value + "%"

However this code does not work, what is the .text equivalent, im sorry im new to programming in general

Comment: `+` is for adding numeric values.  `&` is for string concatenation.  Use `lblFinalTaxRate.Text = "Tax Rate: " NumUpDownTaxRate.Value.ToString() & "%"`.